# Electric Fields

Tags: voltage

According to this [article](http://www.mapoflife.org/topics/topic_41_Electroreception-in-fish-amphibians-and-monotremes/), the electroreception is an ability used by some animals to navigate through their medium without using vision. It was published [another article](http://amasci.com/emotor/chargdet.html) explaining how to build an electric charge detector.

In order to do some active electroreception experiments (detecting the own electric field, as electric fish do) it would be nice to find some circuit that can generate some kind of field

Does anybody know about a circuit like that? Or a place I can research more?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generating a static field is easy. Just connect a wire to a voltage source, and don't short it out to anything. For example, just connect a foot of wire to each of the terminals of a 9 V battery, and keep those wires from touching each other.

Comment: @Ingac: No, passing "electricity" (whatever that is supposed to mean, "current" perhaps?) thru a idea wire generates a circular magnetic field around the wire, but not a electric field.

Comment: All your ideas are really interesting, thanks you guys. Actually, I'm not an electrical engineer, just a programmer; so for the nonce I can't give my opinion. 

But if you are still interested please check this out: [li1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEoQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnxr.northwestern.edu%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fpublications%2FSilv12a.pdf&ei=bOe4Uqj4KdK4kQf52YCgAQ&usg=AFQjCNGM4EtllIoZI58h-TMBLXRllRFINA&sig2=h7qhSlKsxeRBmYbSvRaq8A&bvm=bv.58187178,d.eW0), [li2](http://www.marine.uq.edu.au/publications/dwhitehead/Collin_whitehead.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what field strength you need, but apparently only a few V/m.  To get 1 V/m, for example, connect wires to each end of a 1.5 V battery and hold them 1.5 m apart.  To get 3 V/m, for example, hold the wires from a 1.5 V better 500 mm apart, a 3 V battery 1 m apart, a 9 V battery 3 meters apart, etc.  Yes, it really is that easy.

A Van de Graaff generator is gross overkill and will create much larger voltages than you probably want.

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate static electric field you can use the oldest method observed on the planet (well, at least the first one documented): rub a piece of amber with a piece of wool.

This electrification effect is not bound to amber and wool, and is generally known as [Triboelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect).

If you need stronger electric fields then you can use [Van de Graaff generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator). These generators are relatively cheap, but can generate enormously strong electric fields. They are not designed to sustain a steady current, but if all you want is a very strong electric field - Van de Graaff is the best solution.

Also note that strong electric fields generated by Van de Graaff generators can lead to electrostatic discharge (small lightning) through the air into your "detector". Such discharge can damage your measurement equipment if it does not have ESD protection in place.

Comment: Those tennis racquet shaped bug zappers produce a more sedate "signal" of about a couple of thousand volts if the Van der Graaf is too high.

Comment: @Andyaka, honestly, i think OP will be good with amber and wool (or comb and someone's head). In fact, if he really tries to model biological electroreception conditions - even these measures are overkill. I just couldn't resist mentioning Van de Graaf - I got a strong empathy towards it because I had a lot of fun with it.

Comment: Yeah I've got one of those zappers and couldn't resist either!!

Comment: Nice idea, but I really doubt that an electric fish would had one of those :)

Comment: I wonder what does really do an [electric organ (EO)](http://www.mapoflife.org/topics/topic_578_Electrolocation-and-electrocommunication-in-weakly-electric-fish/)